# how to store meteor helpers in mongoDB collections, and how we can rendered it from mongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates, meteor

How to store meteor helpers in mongoDB collections, and how we can rendered it from mongoDB collection?

For example i have following field in mongo collection.

```
"templateName":"hello {{userName}} <div> Welcome to Store</div>"
```

in My .js file i want to do

```
userName:function(){
    return "Foo";
}
```

Comment: what is the "templateName" ? You want to save the text `"hello {{userName}} <div> Welcome to Store</div>` into the mongo and then load it as a template?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new collection to keep your templates:

```
MyTemplates = new Mongo.Collection('MyTemplates');
```

Insert your templates inside this collection.

In the template file which you want to load your templates stored in mongodb, write a helper as follows:

```
   Template.YOURTEMPLATENAME.helpers({
        'getMyDynamicTemplate': function () {
          Template.hello = Template.fromString(MyTemplates.findOne({"templateName":"blablabla"}).templateString);
          return 'hello';
        }
    });
```

Put below code in your template's html:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=getMyDynamicTemplate}}
```

For Template.dynamic please refer [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic). And lastly refer [here](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-template-from-string/) for populating your template from string

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and worked it out using Servan's answer as the base. THANK YOU!!!

It didn't work form me with `findOne`, so I changed it to `find(...).fetch()`.

First I added the package:
`meteor add numtel:template-from-string`

My Helper was:

```
Template.YOURTEMPLATENAME.helpers({
      'getMyDynamicTemplate': function () {
        var MyHTML = MyTemplates.find({},{HTML:1}).fetch();
        Template.hello = Template.fromString(MyHTML[0].HTML);
        return 'hello';
      }
  });
```

And then put this code in my template's html:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=getMyDynamicTemplate}}
```

It worked out beautifully!